# My site seems to be loading scripts first on Firefox, preloader not working

Tags: firefox, scripting, load, background-image

So it seems that Firefox loads the background images after everything else. I reorganized my site so the first image is not a background image and thus it seems to load first. Great news...but the other images continue to load at the very end. I intend to optimize them further but I don't think that is the issue.

http://www.nogginusers.com/eco/index.html

Comment: Link to your site, so that we can figure out what is happening!

Comment: http://www.nogginusers.com/eco/index.html